# Is it possible to remove formatting in innerXml?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, webforms, xmldocument

Here is my code:

```
XmlNode test= doc.CreateElement("TEST");
test.InnerXml = "<p>" + "<i>" + "<b>" + "[" + TextBox5.Text + "]" + "</b>" + "</i>" + " 
</p>";
```

Currently it will produce:

```
<TEST>
<p>
<i>
<b>[sometext]</b>
</i>
</p>
</TEST>
```

How can i make it to produce:

```
<TEST>
<p><i><b>[sometext]</b></i></p>
</TEST>
```

**Edit:** Interestingly this workaround produce what i need:

```
XmlNode test= doc.CreateElement("TEST");
XmlNode p = doc.CreateElement("p");
test.AppendChild(p);
p.AppendChild(doc.CreateWhitespace(""));
XmlNode i = doc.CreateElement("i");
p.AppendChild(i);
XmlNode b = doc.CreateElement("b");
b.InnerText = TextBox5.Text
i.AppendChild(b);
```

Comment: That's the same thing: whitespace has no inherent meaning in XML unless properly encoded (eg inside inner text or attributes). Why would it make a difference to you?

Comment: @Charlieface yeah it the same, but i still need it as part of requirement.

Comment: The xml node tree doesn't know about your newlines or indentation between tags. This is all done when you convert the `XmlNode` to a string. You can add a specific text node (that has no tag) that contains a newline if you really need a newline between tags

Comment: What you are asking for is a non-standard format, so if you really need to serialize it like this, you'll have to make your own custom serializer. It's also unclear why `<TEST>` is on a separate line from the rest, which would make it very difficult to implement a serializer for it.

Comment: I suggest you invent your own MML: @Mana Markup Language, because that's just now how XML parsing works. You can try get it to strip *all* whitespace, you would be left with just `<TEST><p><i><b>[sometext]</b></i></p></TEST>`, and no newlines. Or you can encode the whitespace properly as significant whitespace, using an `xml:space` attribute

Comment: i see @Xerillio

Comment: @Charlieface alright ill try to look at xml:space

Comment: @ChristopheDevos i would like to remove only the whitespace between tag <p>,<i> and <b>

Comment: @Mana If you only want specific elements, then I think that you are better off creating your own xml writer that can disable the indentation for specific elements. I have also seen an example on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextwriter.formatting#remarks that resembles what you want to achieve.

Comment: @ChristopheDevos i already found my answer, already put as "Edit" in post :)